# How to fix InflateException:Error inflating class com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton

Tags: java, android

> Elegant Class:

```
public class MainHome extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private List<Vegitable> vegitablesList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    //Buttons
    Button addButton;
    ElegantNumberButton countButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_home);


        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainHome.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please waiting...!");
        progressDialog.show();


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Vegitables");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        recyclerView =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //get firebase
        firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference=firebaseDatabase.getReference("vegetables");
        vegitablesList=new ArrayList<>();
        loadVegitables();
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        //Buttons for quntity and add to cart
        countButton=(ElegantNumberButton)findViewById(R.id.number_counter);
        if(countButton != null) {
            countButton.setOnClickListener(new ElegantNumberButton.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String num = countButton.getNumber();
                    Toast.makeText(MainHome.this, "Quantity:" + num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        } 

    }
```

I am setting up Elegant number Button in my application. It will show an exception like `com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView`. I want to display each type vegetable when i was clicked add button Elegant button was visible to user. I dont know how to rectify my problem. Thank u.

I am new to android.

```
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
     View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_listitems, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}
```

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:elevation="@dimen/cell"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameVegitable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#5396FA"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inrlogo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#B87461"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
            android:textColor="#F31F6C"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_btn"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="265dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:onClick="addCart"
            android:text="ADD"
            android:background="@drawable/design_button"/>

        <com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton
            android:id="@+id/number_counter"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="265dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/design_button"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:initialNumber="0"
            app:finalNumber="20"/>



    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> Java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton;
import com.example.greenfresh.model.Vegitable;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Vegitable> listVegitables;
    private Context context;

    public MyAdapter(List<Vegitable> listVegitables, Context context) {
        this.listVegitables = listVegitables;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
         View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_listitems, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(listVegitables.get(position).getImage(), "drawable",
                context.getPackageName());

         holder.image.setImageResource(resourceId);
         holder.vegitableName.setText(listVegitables.get(position).getName());
         holder.price.setText(listVegitables.get(position).getPrice());
        holder.qunType.setText(listVegitables.get(position).getQunType());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listVegitables.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView image;
        public TextView vegitableName;
        public TextView price;
        public TextView qunType;
        public ElegantNumberButton countButton;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            vegitableName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameVegitable);
            price=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            qunType=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.inrlogo);
            countButton=(ElegantNumberButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.number_counter);

        }
    }
}
```

> Elegant Number Class:

```
countButton=(ElegantNumberButton)findViewById(R.id.number_counter);
        if(countButton != null) {
            countButton.setOnClickListener(new ElegantNumberButton.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String num = countButton.getNumber();
                    Toast.makeText(MainHome.this, "Quantity:" + num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
```

I expect the output Elegant Number button on each vegetable type.

Comment: Can you please share your layout as well? Looks like you do not have the setup in your layout for your custom view.

Comment: Post your layout with ViewHolder

Comment: can you please post "ElegantNumberButton" class code

Comment: share your ElegantNumberButton class